# Qual a diferença entre SET e ENUM no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, enums, set

Quais as diferenças entre `SET` e `ENUM` no MySQL? E em quais situações ambas são aplicadas da melhor maneira?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TL;DR

`SET` permite salvar uma coleção. `ENUM` permite apenas valores unitários.

---

### Documentação

De acordo com a documentação do MySQL [**ENUM and SET Constraints**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/constraint-enum.html):

> `ENUM` and `SET` columns provide an efficient way to define columns that can contain only a given `SET` of values. See Section 11.4.4, “The `ENUM` Type”, and Section 11.4.5, “The `SET` Type”.
>
> With strict mode enabled (see Section 5.1.8, “Server SQL Modes”), the definition of a `ENUM` or `SET` column acts as a constraint on values entered into the column. An error occurs for values that do not satisfy these conditions:
>
> - An `ENUM` value must be one of those listed in the column definition, or the internal numeric equivalent thereof. The value cannot be the error value (that is, 0 or the empty string). For a column defined as ENUM('a','b','c'), values such as '', 'd', or 'ax' are invalid and are rejected.
> - A `SET` value must be the empty string or a value consisting only of the values listed in the column definition separated by commas. For a column defined as SET('a','b','c'), values such as 'd' or 'a,b,c,d' are invalid and are rejected.

Em tradução livre:

> As cláusulas `ENUM` e `SET` fornecem uma maneira eficiente de definir colunas que podem conter apenas um determinado conjunto de valores. Consulte a Seção 11.4.4, "O tipo ENUM" e a Seção 11.4.5, "Tipo SET".
>
> Com o modo estrito habilitado (`strict mode`) (consulte a Seção 5.1.8, "Modos SQL do Servidor"), a definição de uma cláusula `ENUM` ou `SET` atua como uma restrição nos valores inseridos na coluna. Ocorre um erro para valores que não satisfazem estas condições:
>
> - Um valor `ENUM` deve ser um dos listados na definição da coluna, ou seu equivalente numérico interno. O valor não pode ser o valor do erro (ou seja, 0 ou a string vazia). Para uma coluna definida como `ENUM` ('a', 'b', 'c'), valores como '', 'd' ou 'ax' são inválidos e são rejeitados.
> - Um valor `SET` deve ser a string vazia ou um valor que consiste apenas nos valores listados na definição da coluna separada por vírgulas. Para uma coluna definida como `SET` ('a', 'b', 'c'), valores como 'd' ou 'a, b, c, d' são inválidos e são rejeitados.

---

> Em quais situações ambas são aplicadas da melhor maneira?

A diferença básica é que quando você define a coluna como `SET`, é possível armazenar mais de valor da lista. Já no `ENUM` só é possível inserir um valor.

No caso abaixo os registros serão incluídos normalmente, já que podem ser utilizados valores isolados ou a combinação dos atributos:

```
CREATE TABLE teste_set (
  fruta SET('banana', 'laranja', 'abacaxi')
);

INSERT INTO teste_set (fruta) VALUES ('banana');
INSERT INTO teste_set (fruta) VALUES ('banana,laranja');
```

No código abaixo a segunda inserção ficará com a coluna `fruta` vazia já que cada valor só pode ser inserido uma vez:

```
CREATE TABLE teste_enum (
  fruta ENUM('banana', 'laranja', 'abacaxi')
);

INSERT INTO teste_enum (fruta) VALUES ('banana');
INSERT INTO teste_enum (fruta) VALUES ('banana,laranja');
```

Comment: Eu ia postar a mesma coisa pois está assim na documentação. Não entendi o porque do -1.

Comment: Obrigado pelo esclarecimento @Sorack

Answer (score 10):

SET e ENUM são usados quando os valores a serem armazenados são escolhidos de um conjunto fixo de valores. Você define colunas de ambos os tipos em termos de valores de strings, mas o MySQL os representa internamente como valores inteiros. Isto leva a um armazenamento muito eficiente, mas pode ter alguns resultados surpreendentes, a menos que você tenha em mente esta dualidade string/inteiro.

**ENUM**

O tipo ENUM é um tipo de enumeração. Uma definição de coluna deste tipo inclui uma lista de valores permitidos, cada um dos quais sendo chamado de "membro" da lista. Cada valor armazenado na coluna deve ser igual a um dos valores da lista.

ENUM ('Ásia', 'Europa', 'USA', África', 'Oceania', Antártida', 'America do Sul')

Os valores na definição do tipo ENUM são dados na forma de uma lista de strings entre aspas separadas por virgulas. Internamente, o MySQL armazena as strings como números inteiros, usando os valores 1 a n para uma coluna com n membros na enumeração. A declaração `insert into paises(nome,continente) values('Kenya','Africa');` atribue o valor 'Africa' da enumeração à coluna do continente. O MySQL na realidade atribui o valor 4, porque 'Africa' é o quarto nome de continente listado na definição de enumeração.

O MySQL reserva o valor 0 como um membro implícito de todas as colunas do tipo ENUM. Por exemplo, se você atribuir "E.U.A' na coluna dos continentes, o MySQL irá armazenar o valor 0, em vez de algum valor de 1 a 7, porque 'E.U.A' não é um membro válido da enumeração. Se você selecionar a coluna mais tarde, o MySQL exibe valores 0 como '' (a string vazia).

**SET**

O tipo de dados SET, como o ENUM, é declarado usando-se uma lista de strings entre aspas separadas por virgulas que definem seus membros válidos. Contudo, diferentemente de ENUM, uma deterinada coluna do tipo SET pode receber a atribuição de um valor consistindo de qualquer combinação desses membros. A seguinte declaração contém uma lista de sintomas exibidos por pessoas que sofrem de alergia:

```
SET ('espirro','nariz entupido', ' cabeça constipada', olhos vermelhos')
```

Um paciente pode ter qualquer um ou todos (ou nenhum) destes sintomas, e os valores de sintoma, portanto, podem conter de zero a quatro membros individuais deste SET, separados por virgulas. As declarações a seguir gravam na coluna, respectivamente, uma string vazia (não há membros do SET), um único membros do SET e múltiplos membros do SET:

```
INSERT INTO alergia (sintoma) Values('');
INSERT INTO alergia (sintoma) Values('cabeça constipada');
INSERT INTO alergia (sintoma) Values('espirro', 'olhos vermelhos');
```

O MySQL representa colunas do tipo SET como um bitmap usando um bit por membro, de modo que elementos na definição sintoma têm valores internos de 1,2,4 e 8 (isto é, eles têm os valores dos bits 1 até 3 em um byte) Internamente, o MySQL armazena os valores mostrados nas declarações INSERT anteriores como 0 (nenhum bit ligado), 4 (bit 2 ligado) e 9 (bits 0 e 3 ligados, ou seja, 1 mais 8).

Uma definição de SET pode conter 64 membros. O armazenamento interno requerido para os valores do SET depende do número de elementos (1,2,3,4 ou 8 bytes para conjuntos de até 8, 16, 24, 32 ou 64 membros. Já uma definção de coluna di tipo ENUM pode listar até 65.535 membros.

Se você tentar armazenar um membro inválido em uma coluna do tipo SET, ele é ignorado, porque não corresponde a nenhum dos bits na definição da coluna. Poe exemplo, gravar um valor de sintoma com `tosse, espirro, respiração ofegante` resulta em um valor interno igual a 1 (espirro). Os elementos `tosse e respiração ofegante` são ignorados porque não estão listados na definição da coluna como membros válidos.

**Conforme mencionado no primeiro paragrafo desta resposta**, a conversão entre as representações em string e numérica de valores dos tipos ENUM e SET podem resultar em surpresas se você não for cuidadoso. Por exemplo, embora você normalmente fosse se referir a uma coluna do tipo enumeração usando as formas de strings de seus valores, também pode usar os valores numéricos internos. O efeito disso pode ser muito sutil se os valores em string se parecerem com números. Suponha que você defina uma tabela t da seguinte maneira

```
CREAT TABLE t (idade INT, irmãos ('0', '1', '2', '3', '>3'));
```

Neste caso, os valores da enumeração são as strings `'0', '1', '2', '3', '>3'`, e os valores numéricos internos são 1,2,3,4 e 5, respectivamente. Agora suponha que você execute a seguinte declaração:

```
INSERT INTO t (idade, irmãos) VALUES (14, '3');
```

O valor da coluna irmãos é especificado aqui como a string '3', e este é o valor atribuído à coluna no novo registro. Entretanto, você também pode especificar o valor de irmãos como um número, como segue:

```
INSERT INTO t (idade, irmãos) VALUES (14, 3);
```

Todavia, neste caso, 3 é interpretado como o valor interno, o qual corresponde ao valor '2' da enumeração! O mesmo princípio se aplica às recuperações. Considere as duas declarações a seguir:

```
SELECT * FROM t WHERE  irmãos = '3';

SELECT * FROM t WHERE  irmãos = 3;
```

No primeiro caso, você obtém registros que possuam um valor na enumeração igual a '3'. No segundo caso, você obtém registros onde o valor interno é 3, ou seja, registros com valor na enumeração igual a '2'.

Fonte: MySQL Guia de Estudo para Certificação

Comment: Brincadeira né, texto retirado do Guia de Estudo para Certificação MySQL e tem gente dando downvoto, esse rapaz do down deve se achar o Deus do MySQL para poder dar um -1. Gostaria de ver a resposta dele caso tenha uma.

Comment: Não tem, mas é assim mesmo, pessoal não justifica o `downvote`, fica difícil saber o que tem de "errado" na resposta

Comment: Exato, vou entrar com uma ação pedindo o dinheiro que paguei pelo livro de volta pois um membro desse site não achou isso certo.

Comment: Acredito que alguem esteja me perseguindo por algum motivo que não sei. Não é a primeira vez que isso acontece. Talvez inveja... quem sabe. Esse tipo de conduta deveria ser passível de monitoração e dependendo do entendimento uma suspensão ou mesmo banimento

Comment: Não presuma que é perseguição, olhe que o @Sorack também ganhou downvote, e essa historia de ninguem comenta já foi discutido no Meta, tem usuário que comenta o problema de uma resposta e ao invés do autor levar como critica construtiva prefere ficar achando que é vitima, ou seja é por experiencia ruim e má aceitação de muitos usuários contra as criticas que claramente são muitas vezes úteis que o pessoal fica sem vontade de comentar, se as pessoas passarem a receber melhor as criticas provavelmente vocês irão ver muitos comentários, mas enquanto a maior parte agir assim, se sentido atacado...

Comment: ... ou vitima, dificilmente os usuários vão comentar, então a comunidade aprender aceitar criticas é um passo enorme para uma melhor comunidade. PS: não vi nenhum problema nem na sua resposta nem na do @Sorack, então deixo um +1 para cada um.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, concordo plenamente com você!  Eu fui um desses e hoje entendo e aceito criticas numa boa e até agradeço quem faz. Mas esse caso em particular passou dos limites do bom senso de quem deu down pois me faz entender que essa materia desse livro não é correta ou eu não deveria compartilhar.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Ressalto que não fui eu quem dei o -1. Creio que o -1 vai da opção de cada um, o négocio é aceitar por mais que esteja correto a resposta, deixo meu +1. Eu fiz uma pergunta no meta a um tempo atrás sobre o tema [O que fazer quando recebo downvotes sem motivos?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5846/o-que-fazer-quando-recebo-downvotes-sem-motivos)

Comment: LeoCaracciolo não dá pra saber o motivo, é possivel que exista algum problema nas respostas que nem eu, nem você e nem o @Sorack notamos, não dá pra sair acusando gratuitamente, eu mesmo já ganhei downvote em respostas, algumas eu achava que estava totalmente corretas, mas tinham sim um ou outro problema, não estava inteiramente errada, mas existia um detalhe ou outro errado. Não estou dizendo que não existe perseguição, é possivel que exista, mas também é possivel que seja apenas impressão, como disse, não dá para afirmar.

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo na realidade existe um sistema preventivo contra "perseguição". Se você receber muitos `downvotes` da mesma pessoa o sistema identifica que existe algo errado e reverte as votações consideradas abusivas. Mas isso não é instantâneo, então fica tranquilo que se acontecer isso o sistema reverte (já aconteceu comigo e atesto que funciona)

Comment: Só posso dizer o seguinte: se há algum motivo para downvoto nessa resposta, a qual nenhum de nós conseguiu enxergar, e o autor do down conseguiu ver, esse moço deve ter um profundo conhecimento a respeito da matéria e por isso ser considerado um senhor da mais alta respeitabilidade por parte da comunidade. Porém ele trilhou o caminho do egoísmo e deixou-nos a ver navios.

Comment: Sabe aqueles problemas de caractere esquisito no PHP?

Comment: @sam to lembrado

Comment: Já resolvi, mas ontem tava dando um problema aqui. Estava fazendo um preg_replace numa palavra e o resultado tava vindo com aquelas interrogações dentro de um losango.