# ENUM ou Boolean?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, mysqli, enums, booleano

Tenho uma tabela `NOTICIA` e nela tenho uma coluna `ATIVO`

A notícia pode ser ativa ou não, se for **BOOLEAN** (0 ou 1) se for **ENUM** (ATIVO ou NAO-ATIVO) .

Qual seria melhor usar, **BOOLEAN** ou **ENUM** ?

Comment: Ao meu ver, é ativa ou não, claramente é booleano. Agora, se houver mais de dois estados, enum, por exemplo, status: publicada, rascunho, excluída, pendente, etc.

Comment: Possível duplicata de [BIT(1) versus TINYINT(1) para valores booleanos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/108842/bit1-versus-tinyint1-para-valores-booleanos)

Answer (score 3):

Desde o MySQL 5.0.3 você tem o tipo `BIT(quantidade de bits)` que pode servir para estes casos, se especificar `BIT(1)`.

`Boolean` é apenas um *alias* para `TINYINT(1)`.

`Enum` como o próprio nome já diz, é para enumerações, ou seja, uma lista de valores "nominados", internamente é armazenado como número, acaba não sendo melhor do que e o  `Boolean` internamente.

Alguns links que podem interessar sobre estes tipos:

> [Qual a diferença entre SET e ENUM no MySQL?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/241439/70)

> [BIT(1) versus TINYINT(1) para valores booleanos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108842/70)

Answer (score -5):

Sugiro nunca usar BOOLEAN em tabelas, porque é rotina aparecer requisitos a posteriori que exija mais de dois estados. Use ENUM ou mesmo um simples INT.